# Does Clojure repeatedly initiate new class(object) for every function call?

Tags: clojure

What is the low-level operation underneath of the function call?

What kind of Java code will be generated when we call a function from Clojure?

I would like to know the details of it so I can write more performance focused code.

Comment: Every function **definition**, not every function **call**. A function call is just a function call, nothing unusual about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In clojure, anything invoked as a function must implement the `clojure.lang.IFn` interface. This interface includes a overloaded method called `invoke`. Functions are first-class in Clojure, so when you say `(def square (fn [x] (* x x)))`, `square` is assigned to the instance of a class that implements `IFn`.

So to sum up: invoking a function in Clojure incurs the cost of calling a method on an object.

Answer (score 4):

Clojure functions implement [the `IFn` interface](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/javadoc/clojure/lang/IFn.html), which provides the `invoke()` call with numerous different signatures. Unless you're passing more than 20 arguments, in which case a variadic signature is in use, it's just as fast as any other method invocation in the JVM.